# Docusign PHP SDK: how update whole envelope in one call via sdk?

Tags: php, docusignapi

To update my envelope(draft) I'm currently using the following code:

```
$envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($api_client);
$envelope_definition = $this->makeEnvelopeDefinition($envelope_pdo);
$envelope_api->updateDocuments($account_id, $envelope_id, $envelope_definition);
if ($shuld_remove_cc_recipient) {
    $envelope_api->deleteRecipient($account_id, $envelope_id, self::CC_RECIPIENT_ID);
}

return $envelope_api->update($account_id, $envelope_id, $envelope_definition);
```

I want update/delete documents and recipients in one call, just like it is when creating envelope:

```
$envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($api_client);
$envelope_definition = $this->makeEnvelopeDefinition($envelope_pdo);
$envelope_api->createEnvelope($credentials->getAccountId(), $envelope_definition);
```

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single call to update everything only when you CREATE a new envelope.

When you have an EXISTING envelope and want to modify it, you need separate calls to update documents and recipients.